# generate canvas display on other viewers based on the draw on one viewer

Tags: javascript, xtk

I am currently writing a web Interface  purely javascript based. I use xtk to display medical image from dicom format. I display 3 viewers : Z, X and Y. I use a canevas to draw on the Z orientation ( in order, for example to encircle an important part of the displayed image).

I would like to make this draw appear on the other orientations ( to have a good idea of what is being encircled). What would be the more convenient way to do it ? can I for example write a label map and then display it using xtk library ? Should I take care of the difference between world coordinate and the image coordinate ?

Comment: It is actually possible to do it through modification of the labelmap object. If anyone is interested in the way to do it, contact me or ask the question in the current post